# Connecting to SQLServer through Hibernate with Windows Authentication And Tomcat 7

Tags: sql-server, tomcat, windows-authentication

I developed a rest service application which need to interact with sql server database using Windows Authentication. I configured hibernate.cfg.xml with integratedSecurity=true. If I run Apache Tomcat from command line, the rest service rest is ok and can access to db without any problem. If I run Tomcat as service, using Tomcat Monitor I get this error: "The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Users', database 'XXX', schema 'dbo'".

How can I solve?

I tried to start Tomcat from Tomcat Monitor using LogOn info, but the service never starts.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What the error tells you, is that the user with which you are connected to SQL Server does not have the SELECT permission on the table `Users`. Time to check permissions in SQL Server, and grant them at the appropriate level.

Comment: Yes, I'm agree with you, but if I run Tomcat from command line everything is ok instead if I run Tomcat from Tomcat Monitor I get that error. If I use SQL Server Management Studio with the user used in hibernate.cfg.xml I can execute SELECT on the table.

Comment: The account under which the service runs, doesn't have the appropriate permissions. It is probably better not to use integratedsecurity=true and create a specific SQL Server user with the appropriate permissions on the database objects you need.